# How to generate Database Diagram using script?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, database-diagrams

I need to create a SQL script to generate a Database diagram.

It should accept two parameters:

1. DB name
2. Schema

It should create a database diagram in Database Diagrams folder with the underlying tables in the given schema.

I am trying to find the system stored procedure which is being called when we create it by UI.

Please suggest some approach to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 1):

Can you set up some extended event captures or profile traces to capture what happens when you use SSMS to see if you can replicate it via scripts.

or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18246965/how-can-i-script-sql-server-database-diagrams